# PHPExcel works in one view but thows errors in all others

Tags: cakephp-2.0, phpexcel

I have a view that generates an Excel sheet and it works fine.  But now when I go to any other view within that model, I get an error:
        Missing Helper

```
    Error: PHPExcelHelper could not be found.

    Error: Create the class PHPExcelHelper below in file:
    app_myapp/View/Helper/PHPExcelHelper.php

    <?php
    class PHPExcelHelper extends AppHelper {

    }
```

My controller:

```
    App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel', array('file' => 'PHPExcel.php'));
    class InvoicesController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('RequestHandler','PhpExcel');

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js'=>array("Jquery") ,'PHPExcel' );
```

I tried putting the App::import line in the function that is generating the excel sheet but I still get the same error on any other page in the model.

Help/direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing PHPExcel from the helpers line...changing:

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js'=>array("Jquery") ,'PHPExcel' );
```

To this:

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js'=>array("Jquery") );
```